# PHPMailer, phpqrcode, MySQL and Stripe-payment to generate QR-code and send it by email on payment success

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments, phpmailer

I am working with Stripe, PHPMailer, Phpqrcode and MySQL to handle some payment.
My goal is to generate a qr-code and send that attached to an email  when the payment is successful. I am able to generate a qr-code and send it by email, but not on payment.success.

With payment.success I am able to send the data to my database and generate a qr-code and save it as an image, but for some reason I cant combine it with PHPMailer.
I am really confused since I am able to get it to work separately. I am running Stripe in test-mode if that have any effect.
Anyone have an idea?

```
<?php

require_once './stripe-php-9.0.0/init.php';
include 'db.php';
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('xxxxx');

// If you are testing your webhook locally with the Stripe CLI you
// can find the endpoint's secret by running `stripe listen`
// Otherwise, find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings in the Developer Dashboard
$endpoint_secret = 'xxxxx';

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;



try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}
$id = $event->data->object->id;
$amount = $event->data->object->amount_captured;
$currency = $event->data->object->currency;
$customer_email = $event->data->object->billing_details->email;
$customer_name = $event->data->object->billing_details->name;



// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
    case 'charge.succeeded':
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Tynnsuppe (txid, Amount, Currency, Customer_email, Customer_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param("sdsss", $id, $amount, $currency, $customer_email, $customer_name);
      $stmt->execute();
      if (!$stmt) {
        echo "Error";
      }
      $stmt->close();
      $conn->close();



      // QR-code
      include 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

      //The payment-id is the qr-code
      $text = $id;
      
      //Save the qr-code as an image and the name is the payment-id.
      $folder="bilder/qr/";
      $file_name= $text.'.png';
      $file_name=$folder.$file_name;
      QRcode::png($text,$file_name);
      
       
      //SEND MAIL
      require_once('PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$bodytext = "Hei";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetFrom('you@example.com', 'Your Name'); //Name is optional
$mail->Subject   = 'Din billett';
$mail->Body      = $bodytext;
$mail->AddAddress( 'reciver@hotmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'bilder/qr/' . $text . '.png';

$mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'KlubbkveldBillett.pdf' );

return $mail->Send();

        break;
    // ... handle other event types

    default:
        echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
}

http_response_code(200);


?>
```

Comment: "can't" means what exactly? What happens when you run this code? What specifically is the problem? Remember we can't run the code, so it's down to you to describe the behaviour clearly, and if necessary do some simple debugging to narrow down the issue a bit.

Comment: As ADyson said, you’ve not shown what the actual problem is. One thing I noticed is that you’re not importing PHPMailer’s namespaces class names, suggesting you’re using a very old version. I can also see you’re not using composer, which is rarely a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
I did what Synchro said and used composer.

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```